# Database problems when allowing multiple browser persistent log ins

Tags: mysql, cookies, remember-me

I am trying to implement a 'remember me' system with cookies that will remember a user across browsers meaning that if a user logs into a website using browser A and checks 'remember me', and then logs into browser B using 'remember me', he will continue to be automatically logged in regardless of which browser he uses. (checking 'remember me' in browser B will not break his persistent login in browser A).

To do this, I set up my database so that multiple keys can be stored alongside a user id.  When a user logs onto my website, the cookie's value is checked.  If that value is found in the database, the user is assigned a new cookie and that cookie key entry in the database is updated to match.  Other keys are left alone so that other browsers' login persistence will not be affected.  When a user logs out manually, the cookie is checked, the corresponding entry in the database is deleted, and then the cookie is deleted.

The problem comes up when a user manually deletes his cookie.  If the user does this, I have no way of deleting the corresponding entry in the database.  It will simply become a permanent entry in my database.  This was not a problem when I was not trying to support cross-browser 'remember me', but has become a problem by allowing multiple cookie keys to be stored.

Is there any way that I can fix / avoid this?

There is a ton of information out there on persistent logins, but persistent logins across browsers never seems to be covered, so any help would be great.  (Also feel free to critique my approach and any security issues.  It seemed way more secure when I was only allowing one 'remember me' per user, but persistent log ins across browsers seems like functionality that users would want).

I am using MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @llion's suggestion of setting an expiry on the cookies, in which case you can [schedule](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) a process to clear out expired cookies from the dB.  However, you can make this appear to the user almost as though the cookies are indefinitely persistent by [extending their life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863740/change-cookie-expiry-date-http) whenever you see them.

For the benefit of any other readers interested in this question, I really hope that you are only [storing hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578/623041) of the cookie in your dB.

Comment: Thanks, the schedule link helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with a "remember me (long enough)" solution. Set an expiry on the sessions but make it a lengthy one. Depending on how often you would expect users to login this could be anything from 8 hours to a week to a year plus. Each time they visit with a valid cookie you update the expiry behind the scenes and it appears persistent. If they delete cookies then eventually their session will be removed.

(If you're not actually using sessions, which it doesn't sound like you are, you'd need to add some maintenance coding around this. Probably best to learn about sessions instead of reinventing the wheel.)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question clearly:

There is **no way for you to know of rogue remember_me tokens on the wild**, the only real solution will be to be make your remember_me tokens last only a couple of weeks, then **cron-job or daemon kill them**.

This fixes your **DB overcrowding** which seems to be the use case of your request.

Please take a note you are facing a reality problem, where there is no way you can guess when a user has deleted the cookie, no backprocess is fired from the browser or other method, so **the only approach will be to kill them regularly if not used**, and refresh the expiration date once used.

The way you describe your system is **more secure**, (if done right) that long live php sessions, so i suggest you keep your current approach, secure it with series+tokens, and kill the unused for a couple of weeks long_live tokens.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

ummm, what happens if he is on another machine and uses a browser, same login?  it's sure to happen.  in our house I do this all the time.  I have 3 boxes downstairs and my mother has 2 machines upstairs.

maybe you can guarantee a session is unique using microtime and the UA string from navigatior.userAgent

but you can't get the computername.  but you could possibly get their IP address through the JS api. http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-system-info-api-20100202/#network  but using this might trigger some sort of warning dialog in the browser. nope.  doesn't work.

java can get the ip.